# Is white lies allowed?

Tags: hadith, salat, sin, belief, life

I am a student. And I have to give presentations and group work. I have done my group work but I feel to embarrass to or public fear of speaking not most of the time bc I want avoid it. And this is taken at Friday. Which will affect my prayer and some others work. So I told them I will do my part but just present it. Because I will be out of town. Is it sinful ? To avoid matter like this ? Because I’m not that strong about my presentation skill. I feel embarrassed.

Comment: can you elaborate your question little more ?

Answer (score 1):

I remembered the following hadith

Asma Bint ‘Umais, reported: “On the night of ‘Aishah’s marriage with the Prophet (saaws), a few ladies and I were in her company. When we went to the house of the Messenger of Allah, we did not find anything except a bowl of milk. He drank a little milk from it and then handed it to ‘Aishah. Overcome by bashfulness, she did not take it. “Do not refuse the Prophet of Allah; take the bowl and drink the milk,” we said to her. Shyly, she took the bowl and drank some milk from it.

Then he said, “Pass on the bowl to your companions in order that they may drink from it too.' We said, “We are not hungry.”

The Messenger of Allah (saaws) said, “Do not gather hunger and lies together.'

I said, “O Messenger of Allah! If we had an appetite for saying but we deny having it, would that be considered a lie?

He said, 'That is a little lie, but even a little lie is recorded [in the Book of Deeds]

[(Musnad Ahmad)](https://hadithprophet.com/hadith-30789.html)